# Swift - Autofill does not populate UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, autofill, face-id

When a user uses Autofill (not password generation - rather, when they tap a login and use iCloud Keychain to log in - see [User taps on Autofill item](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow), if FaceID isn't completed immediately, the UITextField does not populate with the user's username and password. It only fills some of the time.

Since my app is written in SwiftUI, I use a custom TextField.

```
struct AutoFocusTextField<V: Hashable>: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    
    
    var id: V
    @Binding var firstResponder: V?
    
    var onCommit: () -> Void
    var formatText: () -> Void
    
    var inputAccessoryView: UIToolbar? = nil
    
    var secureEntry: Binding<Bool>? = nil
    var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType
    var autoCorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType
    var capitalize: UITextAutocapitalizationType
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    var contentType: UITextContentType?
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker?
        
    init(text: Binding<String>, placeholder: String, id: V, firstResponder: Binding<V?>, onCommit: @escaping (() -> Void) = {}, formatText: @escaping (() -> Void) = {},
         secureEntry: Binding<Bool>? = nil, returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType = .default, autoCorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType = .no, capitalize: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none, keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default, contentType: UITextContentType? = .none, datePicker: UIDatePicker? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        _text = text
        _firstResponder = firstResponder
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        
        self.onCommit = onCommit
        self.formatText = formatText
        
        
        self.secureEntry = secureEntry
        self.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
        self.autoCorrection = autoCorrection
        self.capitalize = capitalize
        self.keyboardType = keyboardType
        self.contentType = contentType
        self.datePicker = datePicker
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text,
                           format: format,
                           onStartEditing: startedEditing,
                           onEndEditing: finishedEditing,
                           onReturnTap: returnTap)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "primary-gray"),
                                                                                               NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "MDPrimer-Regular", size: 16)
                                                                                              ])
        textField.textColor = UIColor(named: "primary-black")
        textField.font = UIFont(name: "MDPrimer-Regular", size: 16)
        textField.tintColor = UIColor(named: "primary-black")
        
        if let datePicker = datePicker {
            textField.inputView = datePicker
            datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        }
        else {
            textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
        }
        
        textField.tintColor = UIColor(named: "primary-lilac")!
        
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = secureEntry?.wrappedValue ?? false
        textField.autocorrectionType = autoCorrection
        textField.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
        textField.autocapitalizationType = capitalize
        textField.textContentType = contentType ?? .none
        textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        textField.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
        
        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        if id == firstResponder, uiView.isFirstResponder == false {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func startedEditing() {
        if id != firstResponder {
            firstResponder = id
        }
    }
    
    func finishedEditing() {
        guard id == firstResponder else { return }
        firstResponder = nil
    }
    
    func format() {
        self.formatText()
    }
    
    func returnTap() {
        self.onCommit()
    }
}

protocol TextFieldReturnKeyProtocol {
    func returnTapped()
}


class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate, TextFieldReturnKeyProtocol {
    @Binding private var text: String
    private let format: (() -> Void)
    private let onStartEditing: (() -> Void)
    private let onEndEditing: (() -> Void)
    private let onReturnTap: (() -> Void)
    var previousText: String?
    var nextText: String?
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, format: @escaping (() -> Void), onStartEditing: @escaping (() -> Void), onEndEditing: @escaping (() -> Void), onReturnTap: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        _text = text
        self.onStartEditing = onStartEditing
        self.onEndEditing = onEndEditing
        self.onReturnTap = onReturnTap
        self.format = format
        
        super.init()
    }
    
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.text = textField.text ?? ""
            self?.format()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        self.text = df.string(from: sender.date)
    }
    
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        onStartEditing()
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        onEndEditing()
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        returnTapped()
        return true
    }
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard var safeText = textField.text else { return true }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            var str = string
            
            if string.count > 1 && textField.textContentType == .telephoneNumber && textField.keyboardType == .numberPad {
                if string.count > 11 && string.starts(with: "+1") {
                    str.removeFirst(2)
                    textField.text = str
                } else if string.count > 10 && string.starts(with: "1") {
                    str.removeFirst()
                    textField.text = str
                }
            }
        }
        return true
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func returnTapped() {
        onReturnTap()
    }
}
```

This is wrapped in a larger SwiftUI view.

```
struct AutoFocusTextFieldWrapper: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    let id: ResponderFields
    @Binding var firstResponder: ResponderFields?
    let onCommit: () -> Void
    
    var hasError: Bool = false
    
    var secureEntry: Binding<Bool>? = nil
    var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType = .default
    var autoCorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType = .no
    var capitalize: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default
    var contentType: UITextContentType? = .none
    var datePicker: UIDatePicker? = nil
    
    var formatText: () -> Void
    var enableBorder: Bool = true
    var highlight: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        AutoFocusTextField(text: $text, placeholder: placeholder, id: id, firstResponder: $firstResponder, onCommit: onCommit, formatText: formatText, secureEntry: secureEntry, returnKeyType: returnKeyType, autoCorrection: autoCorrection, capitalize: capitalize, keyboardType: keyboardType, contentType: contentType, datePicker: datePicker)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 24, bottom: 0, trailing: 24))
            .frame(height: 48)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

And then, here is the Login View.

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @EnvironmentObject var loginRegistrationViewModel: LoginRegistrationViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: LoginViewModel

    var dismiss: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                NavigationTitle(title: viewModel.navigationTitle, description: viewModel.navigationDescription, backButtonAction: dismiss)
                
                AutoFocusTextFieldWrapper(
                    text: $viewModel.email,
                    placeholder: "Email",
                    id: .loginEmail,
                    firstResponder: $viewModel.firstResponder,
                    onCommit: {
                        viewModel.firstResponder = .loginPassword
                    },
                    hasError: viewModel.hasError,
                    returnKeyType: .next,
                    keyboardType: .emailAddress,
                    contentType: .username,
                    formatText: {},
                    highlight: viewModel.successLoggingIn
                )
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 48, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                
                AutoFocusTextFieldWrapper(
                    text: $viewModel.password,
                    placeholder: "Password",
                    id: .loginPassword,
                    firstResponder: $viewModel.firstResponder,
                    onCommit: {
                        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                    },
                    hasError: viewModel.hasError,
                    secureEntry: .constant(true),
                    returnKeyType: .next,
                    contentType: .password,
                    formatText: {},
                    highlight: viewModel.successLoggingIn
                )
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 24, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))

                
                Spacer()

                }
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
```

For some reason, the autofill does not always work. I've noticed that if I comment out the code in `startedEditing` and `finishedEditing`, it seems to work more consistently. Any idea on why it's not working all the time?